# Excel VBA Rename Filename

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to remove file which contains "-". Please advise the following. Thanks

the filename is just random

```
XXXXX- XXXXXX_.pdf
XXXXX - XXXXX - XXXXXX_.pdf
XXXXX.pdf
```

1. My Code below doesn't through all the documents. The loop just keep looping the first document
2. How do I return the nname into my original document?

```
Sub Remove_Special()
    Dim ffile As String
    Dim pathname As String
    pathname = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\TestFile2\"
    ffile = Dir(pathname)
While ffile <> ""

    nname = Replace(ffile, "-", "")
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: After the `nname ...` line, you need to add the line `file = Dir` So that `ffile` continues to store the next file’s name

Comment: Also how do i store the nname into my original document name? Thanks

Comment: `Name "filename old" As "filename new"` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code does exactly what you want. You ffile shouldn´t be a string but a variant.

```
    Sub LoopAllFilesInAFolder()
    Dim ffile As Variant, path As String
    path = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\TestFile2\"
    ffile = Dir(path)
    While ffile  ""
        Debug.Print ffile
        old_name = path & ffile
        new_name = path & Replace(ffile, "-", "")
        Debug.Print old_name
        Debug.Print new_name
        Name old_name As new_name
        ffile = Dir
    Wend
    End Sub
```

The line
`Name old_name As new_name` is the one which changes the name. The `Debug.print` lines can be deleted but i think its sometimes practical to see in the console what it does.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. your code works well. Could you help me with another issue?[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65715270/vba-rename-by-adding-a-space

Comment: Just ask, i´ll see what i can do.