# VBA rename by adding a space

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a space in between a document name. However the code can't pass  through the `IF True` line.

Document name having random name as below:

```
INV500TAT1234 Rev 1 Form_Health.pdf
```

Wanted it to be:

```
INV500 TAT1234 Rev 1 Form_Health.pdf #with a space in between 500 & TAT
```

Note that some of the document does already contain `INV500 TAT`, so I wrote the `if` to skip them

```vb
Sub Rename_Space()
    Dim ffile As Variant, path As String
    path = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Rename\"
    ffile = Dir(path)
    While ffile <> ""
        If ffile = "INV500TAT*" Then
            old_name = path & ffile
            new_name = path & "INV500 TAT*"
            Name old_name As new_name
        End If
        ffile = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems, you want to check if space exists on specific place... `If ffile Like "INV500TAT*" And Mid(ffile, 10, 1)<>" " Then`

Comment: Clearly `INV500TAT1234 Rev 1 Form_Health.pdf` *does not equal* `INV500TAT*`, so the `If` is quite correctly not entered. If it were entered, you would have the next problem of trying to create a file name that contains a `*` which is an invalid file name character. If you were to fix that too, you would have the next problem of changing the list of files while enumerating it with `Dir`, which leads to [various consequences](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160210-00/?p=93011).

Comment: sorry, i have edited the wild card * in the code. My original code has them

Comment: wild cards only work with the `Like` operator but not with `=` which means *"equal"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will make a space in every filename which starts with `INV500TAT` between the `500` and `TAT`.

```
Sub Rename_Space()
    Dim ffile As Variant, path As String
    path = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Rename\"
    ffile = Dir(path)
    While ffile <> ""
    Debug.Print ffile
        If Left(ffile, 9) = "INV500TAT" Then
        old_name = path & ffile
        new_name = path & Left(ffile, 6) & " " & Mid(ffile, 7, Len(ffile))
        Name old_name As new_name
        End If
        ffile = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```